# 9V battery positive soldering pad went off from my circuit board

Tags: soldering, copper

OK, so I got a little problem. Today I was soldering something on this circuit board and the positive wire tore apart. I had to resolder the wire, but when I was heating up the old solder to remove it, the copper part went off with the solder too, so I couldn't solder anymore to the 9V positive hole.
I thought this would fix the power circulation from positive to negative but apparently it didn't.. (See pic)
[image: 1]
If I did something wrong, please don't hate on me. I don't understand so much about these paths.

**P.S: Don't mind some of the bad solders, I kind of did some of them in a hurry.**

Comment: So put it in your memoirs then come back here and ask a question.

Comment: What's your actual question? Why it happened? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why it happened:
Too much heat or a cheap pcb, caused the copper pad to delaminate from the board. Your bad solder joints show that you aren't soldering correctly, which is likely 70% of the problem.

What Prevents it from happening:
Practice proper soldering techniques. Use a suitable, clean, hot iron in quick/short contacts with good solder. Invest in rosin. Multiple attempts to solder the same joint will cause delamination, so measure twice cut once.

How to fix it once it happens:
The pad itself can't be fixed. Instead,  Solder to another or multiple points of the board at the same node. If the copper pad bridged two sides of the board, then you have to connect the wires to both sides to do it properly.

Comment: Thanks a ton! It looked like it had to be connected to one more element!